# list of dictionary consolidation

Tags: python, odoo

what i'm trying to do here is "consolidate" similar lines with the same `product_id`,and append it to get `one2many` field in another view `wizard`

I got to fill a `sale_order_line` in my wizard field uing this method;

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    if context is None: context = {}
    res = super(sale_order_consolidation, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)
    picking_ids = context.get('active_ids', [])
    active_model = context.get('active_model')

    if not picking_ids or len(picking_ids) != 1:

        return res
    assert active_model in ('sale.order'),
    picking_id, = picking_ids
    picking = self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(cr, uid, picking_id, context=context)
    items = []
    packs = []
    if not picking.order_line:
        picking.do_prepare_partial()
    for op in picking.order_line:
        item = {
        'ref': op.ref,
        'product_id': op.product_id.id,
        'name': op.name,
        'product_uom_qty': op.product_uom_qty,
        'product_uom': op.product_uom.name,
        'price_standard': op.price_standard,
        'price_unit': op.price_unit,
        'discount_2': op.discount_2,
        #'tax_id': op.tax_id.id,
        'price_subtotal': op.price_subtotal, 
        }
        #if op.product_id:
        items.append(item)

    for rec in items:
        key = d['product_id']
       # the right instruction to add QTY with the same products and append it to packs in order to update my one2many field

    res.update(order_line_consolidation=items)

    return res
```

and what I actually want is :

```
d = [{'product_id': "x" , 'price': 1 , 'Qty': 2},
     {'product_id': "y" , 'price': 5 , 'Qty': 4},
     {'product_id': "x" , 'price': 1 , 'Qty': 1},
     {'product_id': "z" , 'price': 9 , 'Qty': 1},
     {'product_id': "y" , 'price': 5 , 'Qty': 5}
    ]
```

result:

```
d = [{'product_id': "x" , 'price': 1 , 'Qty': 3},
     {'product_id': "y" , 'price': 5 , 'Qty': 9},
     {'product_id': "z" , 'price': 9 , 'Qty': 1},
    ]
```

what I actually looking for is the right way to add QTY with the same products and append it to packs in order to update my one2many field

thanks you for your help, Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using list use dictionary and make the product_id as key:

```
    items = {}
    for op in picking.order_line:
            item = items.get(op.product_id.id, False)
            if item:
                # if we have an item with the same product_id
                # just add the quantity
                item['product_uom_qty'] += op.product.product_uom_qty
            else:
                # create new dictionary and add it to glocal dictionary
                item = {
                    'ref': op.ref,
                    'product_id': op.product_id.id,
                    'name': op.name,
                    'product_uom_qty': op.product_uom_qty,
                    'product_uom': op.product_uom.name,
                    'price_standard': op.price_standard,
                    'price_unit': op.price_unit,
                    'discount_2': op.discount_2,
                    #'tax_id': op.tax_id.id,
                    'price_subtotal': op.price_subtotal, 
                }
                #add in product.id key
                items[op.product_id.id] = item

    # in the end convert the dict to list
    list_item = []
    for dummy, item in items.iteritems():
        list_item.append(item)
```

Comment: PS: AttributeError: 'sale.order.line' object has no attribute 'product' . so just put item['product_uom_qty'] += op.product_uom_qty