# odoo the following fields are invalid

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

In order to consolidate many order lines in one line "quantity, total_price", and try to print it using a button. I got this error `the following fields are invalid order_line_consolidation`, what I did:

1- created a wizard with a One2many field `order_line_consolidation`

```
class sale_order_consolidation(models.TransientModel):

_name = "sale.order.consolidation"
_description = 'consolidation wizard'

order_line_consolidation = fields.One2many('sale.order.line', 'order_id')
```

2- function to consolidate lines, 
[list of dictionary consolidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517038/list-of-dictionary-consolidation)

3- print function

```
def print_quotation(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):


    datas = {}
    if context is None:

        context = {} 
    data = self.read(cr, uid, ids)[0]
    datas = {   'ids': [],
                'model': 'sale.order',
                'form': data
                }

    return {'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
            'report_name': 'sale.report_saleorder',
            'datas': datas
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your the fields in `sale_order_consolidation` can't be stored in your database, so all you have to do is add `store=True`.
What I suggest:

1- create your own report (custom report) to print it. thn do the following;

```
class sale_order_consolidation(models.Model):

    _name = "sale.order.consolidation"
    _description = 'consolidation wizard'

    order_line_consolidation = fields.One2many('sale.order.consolidation.line', 'order_id')
```

print method:

```
def print_quotation2(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    return self.pool['report'].get_action(cr, uid, ids, 'your_module_name.report_report_name', context=context)
```

second model:

```
class SaleOrderLineconsolidation(models.Model):
     _name = "sale.order.consolidation.line"

     order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order.consolidation','order id',store=True)
     sale_id  = fields.Many2one('sale.order.line','sale_id',store=True)

     field = fields.Char(string='field',store=True)
     .      .       .
     .      .       .
     ...other fields......
```